# how to get same password hash(md5()) as phpbb3

Tags: hash, passwords, md5, forum, phpbb

i have on my page phpbb3 and now I am also starting some advertisementing... So basicly want to have a form where i fill a username and password, then I want the script to hash and md5 the password (the same way as my phpbb3 does) and compare the password and username with table forum_users.... whatever I do I just cant make that works...

```
<?php

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
include ("../Forum/common.php");
include ("../Forum/includes/functions.php");


$pass = "password";
$hash = phpbb_hash($pass);

echo $hash;

?>
```

it doesnt do anything actually

Comment: Your question is fairly unclear but to md5 hash something use either md5($pass) or hash('md5',$pass). I believe the second option is just a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to authenticate the username and password that your user is providing to you against what is in the database then this is all you should need:

```
<?php
/**
*
* Login script for phpBB using username/password
* Used for website authentication
*
*/
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/./';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include("common.php");
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

$username = request_var('username', '');
$password = request_var('password', '');

if(isset($username) && isset($password))
{
  $auth->login($username, $password, true);
}
?>
```

But if you still wish to figure out the PHPBB password encryption hash, it is no longer MD5 in version 3.0 or higher and is a custom hash. Take a look at this thread:

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=585387

I hope this helps.

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Try with the API: http://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.phpbb_check_hash